# sudo command behaviour with quotes

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sudo

I need your help in understanding this behaviour of sudo.

`sudo -s -- 'ls -l'` this command works but `sudo 'ls -l'` throws error saying
`sudo: ls -l: command not found` I realize it treats the entire string within quote as single command (including the spaces) but what I don't get is how does it work fine with `-s` flag but fails when `-s` is not there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without `-s`, the first argument is the name of the command to execute. With `-s`, the first argument is a string passed to the `-c` option of whatever shell (`$SHELL` or your system shell) is used to execute the argument.

That is, assuming `$SHELL` is `sh`, the following are equivalent:

```
sudo -s -- 'ls -l'
sudo -- sh -c 'ls -l'
```

Comment: You could write `sudo -- "$SHELL" -c 'ls -l'` to obviate your assumption.

Comment: `-s` specifically caters to `SHELL` being unset, so I had to assume something, and giving it a specific value seemed simpler.

Comment: Ah, yes - it keeps the answer manageably simple.  I withdraw my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

From the [sudo man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> **-s [command]**
>
> The -s (shell) option runs the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified in
> the password database. If a command is specified, it is passed to the
> shell for execution via the shell's -c option. If no command is
> specified, an interactive shell is executed.

It behaves like it does because a new shell is spawned which breaks up the words in your "quoted command" like shells do.

Comment: so without -s option, its the behavior of sudo command to treat everything mentioned in quotes as one single command.

Comment: Correct. You can try this yourself on the command line of an interactive shell where `"ls -l"` will yield the error `ls -l: command not found` because the shell is literally looking in the path for a command with a space in it, just as you asked it to.